# How DNS message compression avoids collision of labels and pointers?

Tags: dns, binary, hex

While reading up on RFC 1035 (a.k.a DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION) I found the following:

> 4.1.4. Message compression
>
> In order to reduce the size of messages, the domain system utilizes a
> compression scheme which eliminates the repetition of domain names in a
> message.  In this scheme, an entire domain name or a list of labels at
> the end of a domain name is replaced with a pointer to a prior occurance
> of the same name.
>
> The pointer takes the form of a two octet sequence:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| 1  1|                OFFSET                   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

> The first two bits are ones.  This allows a pointer to be distinguished
> from a label, since the label must begin with two zero bits because
> labels are restricted to 63 octets or less.  (The 10 and 01 combinations
> are reserved for future use.)  The OFFSET field specifies an offset from
> the start of the message (i.e., the first octet of the ID field in the
> domain header).  A zero offset specifies the first byte of the ID field,
> etc.

Why the "63 octets or less" restriction on labels guarantees that pointers that begin with two one (1) bits will can be distinguished from labels?

Comment: First bit is 2^7 aka 128, and following one is 64. Hence if it is switched you now the value is 64 or more, so reciprocally if the length is 63 or less the bit as to be 0, as well as the other one for 128, hence it can not be an offset.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is in the  same *RFC 1035*

> Each label is represented as a one octet *length* field followed by that
> number of octets.

So the leftmost (first) octet contains the label field length and its maximum value can be `63` or `0011111` binary and the presence of at least one `1` in two highest bits can distinguish label from something else.

Comment: Your explanation makes total sense because you said the *leftmost octet* (which is effectively 1 octect) of the label can be only `63` decimal or `0011111` binary. However, that's no really what the text I mentioned says, it says 63 *octets* or less. Am I missing something?

Comment: Leftmost octet is *is* the first bit. I edited the answer  to make it mire clear.

Comment: Ok, now it's very clear. Summing it up: Because the length (leftmost/first octect) can hold only the value of `63` decimal or `0011111` binary, this means also the label can have a max of 63 octets representing it, hence the restriction mentioned in the question. Thank you for your time.